# Single page load css

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, single-page-application

is it possible to load CSS with a single page loading ?

I'm using single page method with JSF/Primefaces for my web application. I don't manage to load a CSS when I change my single page.

Do you have an idea please ?

Edit : 
I have an index.xhtml with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view />
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        xxx
    </f:facet>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet name="/ressources/css/default.css" />
    </f:facet>

    <!-- ...etc -->

    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form id="contentForm">
                <ui:include id="spa_content" src="ressources/fragments/#{myBean.currentPage.fragment()}.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

You can see the include for update my single page. And the facet "last" to use my default.css

default.css :

```
.ui-button-text {
    background-color: green;
    color : blue;
}
```

I have a managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "xxx")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean extends AbstractSessionBean implements Serializable {

    public MyBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {}

    //...etc

}
```

Finally, I have mySinglePage.css and a fragment mySinglePage.xhtml :

mySinglePage.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet name="/ressources/css/mySinglePage.css" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:commandButton value="#{xxx}" action="#{xxx}"  update="xxx"/>

</ui:composition>
```

You can see the facet last in order to use mySinglePage.css, but it doesn't working...

mySinglePage.css :

```
.ui-button-text {
    background-color: red;
    color : yellow;
}
```

I don't know how to use mySinglePage.css

Edit 2 :

If I have this, it works but my workmate say it is not singlepage :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view />
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        xxx
    </f:facet>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet name="/ressources/css/default.css" />
    </f:facet>

    <!-- ...etc -->

    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <ui:insert name="contenu">
                <ui:include src="/ressources/fragments/mySinglePage.xhtml" 
/>
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="../../index.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="contenu">

            <f:facet name="last">
                <h:outputStylesheet name="/ressources/css/mySinglePage.css" 
/>
            </f:facet>

            <p:commandButton value="BLOP"/>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>   
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

Do you know if it is a good method ?

Thanks.

Comment: _"is it possible to load CSS with a single page loading"_ Yes

Comment: Thanks :) it's a beginning. 
"Do you have an idea please ?". Or a link with tutorial, because I'm trying some things but it doesn't work

Comment: Read [ask]... Questions about things not working should include a [mcve] so we can comment on it (less work)... And questions about links to tutorials are off-topic for stackoverflow.... Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I'm understanding. I'm editing my post.

Comment: I don't see any "mySinglePage.css" what did you **try**? My 'answer' would be: "Do it in the same facet"...

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post and trying "facet last" into my fragment but it doesn't works. I hope that now I don't forget something ^^

Comment: Why in a fragment? Why not plain if you want it there? This is per page custom css, right?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question but my workmate say :
using a template is not a single page
So, we are using this method.

Comment: I Nowhere mentioned templates. With per page I meant per include

Comment: Yes. I have an index.xhtml with <include src="..."> with dynamic src (no <insert...>)
I would like to load CSS "A" when I include a page, and CSS "B" when I include other page.
If I'm using <insert> and <define>, my CSS is loading. But if I'm using only <include>, it doesn't works. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a suggestion to check instead of a providing a solution.

I noticed this part of your code where you spelled resources in a different way.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="/ressources/css/default.css" />
```

Is your folder named ressources?  It may be a very subtle change but I think having the correct syntax for the resources folder might solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kukeltje and Daeik. It is not an issue about path. With FacePainter, it's work better but it's not perfect. Do you know  if I can get a css file with <f:ajax> ?